# Can I configure NHibernate to throw exception when value in db is null?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a situation where I have a table where some of the columns are nullable, but I want my NHibernate-based entities to expose those values as non-nullable fields. If I do this with a normal mapping, NHibernate assigns the defult value of the type to the entity's field in the case of a null value. I would like to change this behavior so that instead an exception is thrown. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify; at which stage in the object's lifecycle should the exception be thrown? eg. when it's loaded or saved/updated?

Comment: In my situation the best solution would be to throw at load. I am now changing my solution to non-nullable properties with nullable backing fields. I add a check in the getter so this means I throw at access time which is probably the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your mapping and add a not-null="true" attribute.